# How to filter across custom event labels in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to create a graph of event labels of a given category when a different category has a different label value.

Confusing, I know, but here's an example.

Let's say I have Custom events with two different categories:

```
Category A: LabelName = "Food"

Category B: LabelName = "Drink"
```

What I need to do is generate a graph of all the LabelNames for category B when the Selected labelName of Category A is "PB&J".

Essentially, What drinks did people who ate PB&J choose ?

I've tried custom segments, but there are over 14,000 possible values for Category A so manually creating a Segment for each is not practical.